# Manipulating viewport width units vw

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to reformat a complex website based on viewport width 'vw' for anything to fit for modern panorama screens. Is there a way to tell browser to treat 1 vw eg. 0.75vw?

Comment: The answer to this question is "No". Is that your actual question though? Or do you have a problem you need to solve that you think this is the appropriate method? If you ask about that problem, you might receive a better answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that there's a better approach to what you're trying to accomplish. Instead of asking what may be an XY question, maybe describe the actual issue.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.             @isherwood: this is the actual issue and I know of all the possible ways to solve. But just to solve it with a litte snippet of javascript would have been unbeatable. PS: Sorry for orthographical mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the 
 Note: "initial-scale=0.75"

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.75">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you Carol, but this does'nt work on desktop. For Mobil there is a special variant of the site. I need to set different vw for desktop monitors  which aspect-ratio is smalller than 1:0.57. I'm just trying for better: live.replace() vs. load-switch for css.